# Adding numbers and counting words from file

Tags: java, readfile

i have to add the numbers from a file and average their sum, and count the number of words. So far i have this but I get an error and i got this. I am trying to get it to distinguish word from letter but I get an error after it runs the first while

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
  public class ReadTextFile
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
{
   String word, line, message, message2;
  int number=0 , numword=0, numnum, numnum2, numnum3, av;
  FileInputStream fis = new  
FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\Douglas\\Desktop\\payroll.txt");
  Scanner in = new Scanner (fis);  

  while (in.hasNext())
  {
     numword++;

     word = in.next();

     message2 = "The word is: "+word+"\n";

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, message2);
  }  
  in.close();

  while(in.hasNextInt())
  {  
     numnum = in.nextInt();

     number++; 

     message = "The  number is: "+numnum+"\n";

     numnum2=numnum;

     numnum3= numnum+numnum2;

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, message);

     av=numnum3/number;
  }
  in.close();

  message = "The number of words processed was "+numword;

  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog (null, message);

  message2 = "The number of numbers processed was "+number+"and the average 
  was "+av;

} 
}
```

Comment: show me the error please !

Answer (score 0):

You are closing scanner after first loop. Then using it again in second loop. remove the first close and close scanner after you finishes all scans.

```
in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the code more readable and working try it.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class ReadTextFile {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String message, message2;
    int number = 0, numnum =0, sum=0;
    double av = 0.0;
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\temp\\file.txt");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(fis);

    while (in.hasNext()) {
        number++;
        numnum = in.nextInt();
        message = "The  number is: " + numnum + "\n";
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

        sum += numnum;
        av = sum / number;
    }

    message = "The number of words processed was " + number + " total is " +sum;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);

    message2 = "The number of numbers processed was " + number
            + " and the average was " + av;
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message2);

 }
}
```